# A forfeited game in baseball

Tags: rules, baseball, mlb, suspension

Does a forfeited baseball game count as a game played. scenario is Season has not started and one of the teams dropped. The league counted all of the games as wins and scored them 1-0 for the opposing team. One of my players was suspended for 4 games last year with 2 carried over to 2019 which means he is eligible play in game 3. Our series with the team was to start last night and tonight. These two games which are forfeited should they be counted towards the 2 suspended games. Let me know your thoughts. The is american legion we follow MLB rules

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question you need to ask your league organisers; MLB rules don't cover the case of teams not fulfilling their fixtures.